# LibGDX Mouse Edge Scrolling

Tags: java, libgdx, orthographic

I have a game that uses an `OrthographicCamera` and I want to make it so that if the cursor is on the edge of the screen the camera moves in that direction.

I've tried several different ways but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I have so far,

```
    float leftEnd = cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth * cam.zoom) / 2f;
    float rightEnd = cam.position.x + (cam.viewportWidth * cam.zoom) / 2f;
    float topEnd = cam.position.y + (cam.viewportHeight * cam.zoom) / 2f;
    float bottomEnd = cam.position.y - (cam.viewportHeight * cam.zoom) / 2f;

    float x = c.getX();
    float y = c.getY();

    if (x <= leftEnd - (c.getWidth() * c.getScaleX())) {
        target.set(target.getX() - 4, target.getY());
    } else if (x >= rightEnd) {
        target.set(target.getX() + 4, target.getY());
    }

    if (y <= bottomEnd) {
        target.set(target.getX(), target.getY()-4);
    } else if (y >= topEnd - (c.getHeight() * c.getScaleY())) {
        target.set(target.getX(), target.getY()+4);
    }
```

NOTE: `c` is just a sprite to replace the mouse cursor.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What is the result of the posted code? Does it not scroll at all? Does it scroll too soon?

Comment: It scrolls, but the mouse must be way off the screen, I want something where if the mouse is just touching the edge it scrolls

Comment: Try printing out the c.getX() and rightEnd when the mouse are where you want it to scoll right. Then post the values here.